# Convert a string extracted from a dict, to a float

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains rows like these:

```
0001193125-09-111401    AccountsNotesAndLoansReceivableNetCurrent   us-gaap/2008        20081231    0   USD 2570000.0000    
0001193125-09-111401    AccountsNotesAndLoansReceivableNetCurrent   us-gaap/2008        20090331    0   USD 2185000.0000    
0001104659-09-031513    AccountsNotesAndLoansReceivableNetCurrent   us-gaap/2008        20081231    0   USD 1227224000.0000 
0001104659-09-031513    AccountsNotesAndLoansReceivableNetCurrent   us-gaap/2008        20090331    0   USD 1452748000.0000
```

Here is my code for open it:

```
path = "2009q2/num.txt"
with open(path, 'r') as a_file:
      for line in a_file:
      stripped_line = line.strip()
      values_list = stripped_line.split('\t')[0:8]
```

Where `values_list` is a list with the data in each line. Now, I'm making a `dict`:

```
values_dict = {
         'cik': values_list[0][0:10], 
         'accession': values_list[0][10::].replace("-", ""), 
         'tag': values_list[1], 
         'value': values_list[3], 
         'valueid': values_list[6], 
         'date': values_list[4]
         }
```

`values_dict['value']` is a `str` like this `'12345.0000'`. Now, I want to convert this string into a `float`. The final result I need is `12345.0`. So, I tried:

```
float(values_dict['value'])
```

But I get the following error:
`could not convert string to float: 'value'`
I get confused about it and then tried:

```
x = '12345.0000'
print(float(x))
```

output: `12345.0` It works so, what is wrong here?

**EDIT:**
The content of `2009q2/num.txt"` is:

```
0001193125-09-111401    AccountsNotesAndLoansReceivableNetCurrent   us-gaap/2008        20081231    0   USD 2570000.0000    
0001193125-09-111401    AccountsNotesAndLoansReceivableNetCurrent   us-gaap/2008        20090331    0   USD 2185000.0000    
0001104659-09-031513    AccountsNotesAndLoansReceivableNetCurrent   us-gaap/2008        20081231    0   USD 1227224000.0000 
0001104659-09-031513    AccountsNotesAndLoansReceivableNetCurrent   us-gaap/2008        20090331    0   USD 1452748000.0000
```

**EDIT 2**:
**The problem was that the text file contains the following header:**

```
adsh    tag version coreg   ddate   qtrs    uom value   footnote
```

So, when I do `dict["value"]` I get `"coreg"` which is a string. Therefore, `float(values_dict["value"])`raise that error.

Comment: It seems like the problem in `2009q2/num.txt` . Can you provide its content (or its last line, according to the provided code)?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the post

Comment: `could not convert string to float: 'value'` meaning you are trying to convert a variable whose value is `value` to float.

Comment: @NafizAhmed OMG! you are right and I'm stupid hahaha thank you.

Comment: you could also use `isinstance(x, float)` to check whether a value is float or not. If the variable contains float value, returns true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nafiz Ahmed . The problem was the text file header:

```
adsh    tag version coreg   ddate   qtrs    uom value   footnote
```

So, when I do `values_list[7]` it returns `'value'`. Which is not a `float` at all.